# Prevent GC when using Git as a simple KV store

Tags: git

My situation is to use git only as a KV store for directory content. I use `git update-index --add; git write-tree` to add directory and use `git read-tree` to retrieve them when necessary. I will record the SHA1 hash of the tree manually in other ways.

In this scenario, what do I need to config to prevent some git commands to GC these unreachable objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable auto GC by adding it to the config.

From the [Description section](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) in the docs (emphasis mine):

> Some git commands may automatically run git gc; see the --auto flag
>   below for details. **If you know what you’re doing** and all you want is
>   to disable this behavior permanently without further considerations,
>   just do:
>
> `$ git config --global gc.auto 0`

Comment: Would setting `gc.pruneExpire` to `never` do too?

Comment: Prune is not the same as GC as far as I'm aware. `gc.auto` disables garbage collecting altogether, afaik prune is a consequence of GCing so I think `gc.auto` is the way to go here.